# Implement dense_rank() without using analytic function in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Below is the dataset.

```
select * from temp_denserow;
c1  c2  c3  c4
103 1   3   1
204 1   3   2
102 1   3   3
304 1   1   3
203 1   2   1
104 1   2   2
300 3   1   2
201 1   2   2
301 2   1   4
302 2   4   4
303 1   4   3
101 1   3   2
202 1   2   3
```

I am using teradata, where there is no inbuilt dense_rank() function.

DENSE_RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY c3 ORDER BY c3, c4 ) AS new_dense_rank

I tried implementing the above statement, but not able to get the desired output.

```
select emp.*,
       (select count(distinct c3)
        from temp_denserow emp2
        where emp2.c3 = emp.c3 and
              emp2.c4 >= emp.c4
       ) as "new_dense_rank"
from temp_denserow emp;
```

Expected output:

```
301 2   1   4   3
304 1   1   3   2
300 3   1   2   1
202 1   2   3   3
104 1   2   2   2
201 1   2   2   2
203 1   2   1   1
102 1   3   3   3
204 1   3   2   2
101 1   3   2   2
103 1   3   1   1
302 2   4   4   2
303 1   4   3   1
```

Comment: Edit the question add desired result would helpful .

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: For start, if you `partition by c3` you dont need `order by c3`

Comment: You're running an ancient Teradata version (pre-14.10). To get the result of a DENSE_RANK you need nested OLAP-functions, see https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/05/missing-functions-dense-rank

Comment: Or you could upgrade to a version of Teradata that's still in support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Check [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b5950/7) include this query and `DENSE_RANK` from postgresql for comparison

```
select emp.*,
       (select count(distinct c4)
        from temp_denserow emp2
        where emp2.c3 = emp.c3 and
              emp2.c4 >= emp.c4
       ) as "new_dense_rank"
from temp_denserow emp
ORDER BY c3, c4 DESC;
```

Comment: Got me by seconds :) Good job!

Comment: got the output in this format. 1 4 1,
1 3 2,
1 2 3
. I want the output as 1 4 3,
1 3 2,
1 2 1

Comment: I was expecting the same output in a different way sorted out in ascending.

Comment: sorry I still dont see it. can you edit your question and include your desire output as formated text so can understand better.

Comment: change  `emp2.c4 <= emp.c4` to `emp2.c4 >= emp.c4` but in that case you need to add `ORDER BY c4 DESC` to the `DENSE_RANK` too

Comment: It worked, small typo..  emp2.c4 >= emp.c4 replaced with emp2.c4 <= emp.c4

Comment: Please don't implement a Scalar Correlated function like this, performance will probably much worse than Gordon's approach (or one from the link I posted)

Comment: @dnoeth In my defense I don't know teradata so I assume didn't have any window function and just fix op query. But yes, gordon answer look much cleaner.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: No need for defense, Teradata is not known that much. It's mainly for huge Data Warehouses (up to 100 PB), you simply try to avoid inefficient queries against billions of rows :-)

Answer (score 1):

Teradata does support window functions, just not `dense_rank()` (for some reason).  So, I would use window functions:

```
select emp.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by emp.c3 order by emp.c4 rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as new_dense_rank
from (select emp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp.c3, emp.c4 order by emp.c4) as seqnum
      from temp_denserow emp
     ) emp;
```

This should have much better performance than a correlated subquery.

Comment: I am getting different output.  301 2 1 4 0,
300 3 1 2 1,
304 1 1 3 1,
201 1 2 2 1,
203 1 2 1 2,
104 1 2 2 2,
202 1 2 3 2,
204 1 3 2 2,
103 1 3 1 3,
102 1 3 3 3,
101 1 3 2 3,
302 2 4 4 3,
303 1 4 3 4

Comment: @a123 . . . I think I fixed the logic.

Comment: No.. it is not fixed.. 101 1 3 2 2 1,
204 1 3 2 1 2...
Here is the issue..  300 3 1 2 1 1,
304 1 1 3 1 2,
301 2 1 4 1 3,
203 1 2 1 1 1,
104 1 2 2 1 2,
201 1 2 2 2 2,
202 1 2 3 1 3,
103 1 3 1 1 1,
101 1 3 2 2 1,
204 1 3 2 1 2,
102 1 3 3 1 3,
303 1 4 3 1 1,
302 2 4 4 1 2